# Shared memory rights section block c Linux

Tags: c, linux

I’m trying to map to a shared memory with 2 different rights.

From a server point, I’m reading the whole shared memory data part and read/ write mutex part for locking / unlocking the shared memory.

From a client point of view, I’m reading and writing the whole shared memory so no issue on this part.

See below my C code in the Shm.h file:

```
typedef struct 
{
    unsigned int Int1;
    unsigned int Int2;
    unsigned int Int3;
} DataType, *DataTypeHdlr;

typedef struct 
{
    DataType Data;
    pthread_mutex_t Mutex;
} MyShmType, *MyShmTypeHdlr;
```

C code from the ShmRights.c (Server point of view):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Shm.h"

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(void)
{
    int FileDesc;

    DataTypeHdlr MyDataHdler;       /* Data handler */
    pthread_mutex_t* MyMutexHdlr;   /* Mutex handler*/

    /* Init */
    MyDataHdler = NULL;
    MyMutexHdlr = NULL;

    /* Open the Shared memory Read for Data and Write for Mutex */
    FileDesc = shm_open("/Shm1", O_RDWR, 0660);

    /* Check the File Desc validity */
    if (FileDesc == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: Shm open\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Map into different memory regions */
    MyMutexHdlr  = mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                                     MAP_SHARED, FileDesc, 0);

    MyDataHdler = mmap(NULL, sizeof(DataType), PROT_READ,
                            MAP_SHARED, FileDesc, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));

    /* Check that the handler are valid */
    if (MyMutexHdlr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("Error: Mutex handler not valid\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Check that the handler are valid */
    if (MyDataHdler == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("Error: Data handler not valid\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Simple code to take mutex and display shm values */
    pthread_mutex_lock(MyMutexHdlr);
    printf("Info: Int1:%d - Int2:%d -Int3:%d\n", MyDataHdler->Int1, MyDataHdler->Int2, MyDataHdler->Int3);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(MyMutexHdlr);

    return 0;
}
```

In this way, do I correctly map the shared memory section with the correct rights? Is it portable also ?

How can be sure that the pointers return by the mmap function are correctly mapped in the Shared memory sections respectively Data and mutex section ? with DDD ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it is not clear, what is the question/problem here. please add more details.

Comment: So the post was not complete.

Comment: If I have understood properly, you are using two processes, is that right? (processes, no threads). If so, the first thing that call my attention is using mutex with pthreads, instead of IPC primitives. mutex with pthreads is ok when using threads but no for synchronising processes. What is the code of the client process? Finally, what you are getting, and what you are expecting would be helpful to answer your "question". Please rewrite your question to make it clearer.

Comment: If your design is based in two processes, use IPC primitives for the mutex. If your design is based in two threads, use pthreads primitives for the mutex. If your design is based in two threads, they are sharing the memory, you only need to synchronise the access to the memory. does it make sense for your scenario?

Comment: In your question you say "From a client point of view, I’m reading and writing the whole shared memory so no issue on this part.". What is the issue you are getting on the server part?

Comment: I got memory overlapping as written below.

Comment: OT: it is a bad idea to 'typedef' pointers.  Much better to include a '&' or '*' as needed in the actual code

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error: Shm open\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest calling: `perror()` which will output your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred, all to `stderr`

Comment: The issue is not linked to the usage of printf, but I will consider it.

Comment: @user3629249 : what do you mean by typedef pointer ? It allows by the C Standard.

Comment: @user3629249 I’ve checked on a thread (typedef in pointer in c) in this forum and this usage is more a point of view than a C real rule. Also in my case, this notation is a constraint linked to Coding rules. Thanks to ctags or eclipse tags, this ‘hiding’ issue can be easily forgotten fixed.

Comment: It is not against the C rules to hide a pointer in a typedef.  Rather it is related clarity of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, two processes are used but the use of pthread mutex instead of semaphore is also possible as far I’ve read several articles.

The client opens the shared memory and create it if needed. It took the mutex, update the value of data and release the mutex.

The thing I’ve observed it that the values are modified when the mutex is locked or released. So, I thought about a memory overlap or a part not correctly mapped.
B/R